# Poco RWLock - Undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_wrlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5

Tags: c++, gcc, pthreads, poco-libraries

I'm building a daemon application on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and i get a linker error:

```
undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_rwlock_wrlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
```

The code is

```
#include <Poco/RWLock.h>

class DatabaseHandler
{
public:

  typedef std::shared_ptr<DatabaseHandler> Ptr;

  DatabaseHandler() {};
  virtual ~DatabaseHandler() {};

  virtual bool Connect(const STRING& connstring);
  bool Disconnect();

  BOOL IsConnected() {
    return (m_pSession && m_pSession->isConnected());
  }

protected:
  std::unique_ptr<Poco::Data::Session> m_pSession;
  Poco::RWLock m_write_lock;
};


class FADatabaseHandler : public DatabaseHandler
{
public:
  EDBReturnValues UpdateHouse(TFAData& data);

private:
  BOOL HouseExists(const UINT HouseId);
};
```

And the implementation..

```
EDBReturnValues FADatabaseHandler::UpdateHouse(TFAData& data)
{
  Poco::ScopedWriteRWLock lock(m_write_lock);
  .....
}
```

The compiler command line for this file is

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++11 -g -lrt -lm -lpthread -DPOCO_STATIC -DPOCO_NO_AUTOMATIC_LIBS -DUSING_POCO_LIB -DBUILD_AS_SERVER -I/usr/local/mysql/include -c /home/daniele/src/TBServer/FADatabaseHandler.cpp -o obj/Debug/FADatabaseHandler.o
```

If I comment the RWLock.h include, the m_write_lock and the ScopedWriteRWLock calls, I get the error in:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundationd.a(TextEncoding.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_rwlock_wrlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
```

Where I'm wrong?

Regards.

Comment: use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`?

Comment: Hi @yohjp you're right!

Answer (score 2):

If you use CMake, you can do this:

```
...
find_package(Threads)
...

target_link_libraries(
    ...
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
)
```